# Liquify Filter on Smart Object - Mesh not loading after a while

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, filter

I'm working in Photoshop CC 2017 and I use the liquify filter on smart objects frequently. Between saves the liquify filter mesh stops working for some reason. I have tried to replace the smart object with the previously saved version, but the same thing happens.

It also seems that if I drag layers from a file where the liquify filter has stopped working into another file, it makes the "working" file's liquify stop working as well. Super annoying!

I have tried to save the mesh and then reload it when the liquify filter has stopped working, but it doesn't load anything.

Has this happened to anyone else and does anyone know what to do about it?